# Appending string much faster than appending character

Tags: arrays, string, swift, character

I was doing https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-review-loop problem on hacker rank and I was running into a time out issue that was resolved in round about way. I was hoping someone on here can explain to me why one is faster than the other. Or point me to documentation that explains this phenomenon

If you don't have an account here's a description of the issue you feed in the number of test cases and then a string which your code is to create a string with all the characters in the odd indices and a string with all the characters in the even indices. Example input

```
2
Hacker
Rank
```

returns

```
Hce akr
Rn ak
```

Simple right? Here's the code I made.

```
if let line = readLine(), numOftests = Int(line) {
    for iter in 0..<numOftests {
        var evenString = ""
        var oddString = ""
        var string = readLine()!
        var arrChars = [Character](string.characters)                           //1
        for idx in 0..<string.characters.count {
            if idx % 2 == 0 {
                oddString.append(arrChars[idx])                                 //1
                //oddString.append(string[string.startIndex.advancedBy(idx)])   //2 <= Times out
            }
            else {
                evenString.append(arrChars[idx])                                //1
                //evenString.append(string[string.startIndex.advancedBy(idx)])  //2 <= Times out
            }
        }
        print("\(oddString) \(evenString)")
    }
}
```

Originally I used the commented out code. This lead to a time out. To sum my problem is that using the subscripting system for a string, causes it to be a lot slower than indexing an array of characters. It caught me by surprise and if it wasn't for the discussion group in hacker rank I wouldn't have found a solution. Now it goads me because I don't know why this would make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue isn't the speed of appending a string vs. appending a character.  The issue is how long it takes to locate the value you are appending.

Indexing an array is O(1) which means it happens in the same time whether you are accessing the first character or the 97th.  It is efficient because Swift knows the size of the array elements, so it can just multiply the index by the size of the element to find the nth element.

`string.startIndex.advancedBy(idx)` is O(idx).  It will take longer depending on how far you go into the string.  Accessing the 97th character will take about 97 times as long as accessing the first character.  Why? Because characters in Swift are not uniform in size.  Swift strings are fully unicode compatible and a "" takes more bytes to represent than "A".  So, it is necessary to look at every character from the `startIndex` to the one you are accessing.

That said, there is no reason for you to start at `startIndex` each time.  If you kept the current index in a variable, you could advance it by `1` each time which would make the string indexing version about the same speed as the character array indexing version.

```
var currentIndex = string.startIndex

for idx in 0..<string.characters.count {
    if idx % 2 == 0 {
        oddString.append(string[currentIndex])
    }
    else {
        evenString.append(string[currentIndex])
    }
    currentIndex = currentIndex.successor()
}
```

---

That said, I would probably write it like this:

```
for (idx, char) in string.characters.enumerate() {
    if idx % 2 == 0 {
        oddString.append(char)
    }
    else {
        evenString.append(char)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now that you told me that I was able to locate the documentation for that characteristic.