# How can I optimize this code that manipulates strings?

Tags: swift

I am trying to come up with a faster solution to this Hackerrank problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-review-loop

In short, I have to separate each input string into two strings, the first one having the even index characters of the original string and the second one having odd indexes.
The number of strings to be separated are saved to the `numStrings` constant, the strings themselves are stored in `inputString`.

```
import Foundation

let numStrings = Int(readLine()!)!

func printEvenAndOdd(string: String) {       
    var firstString = ""
    var secondString = ""
    var stringIndex = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: 0) 

    for index in 0..<string.characters.count {
        stringIndex = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: index) 

        if index % 2 == 0 {            
            firstString += String(string[stringIndex])
        } else {
            secondString += String(string[stringIndex])
        }
    }           
    print(firstString + " " + secondString)
}

for _ in 1...numStrings {
    let inputString = readLine()!
    printEvenAndOdd(string: inputString)
}
```

My code works, but fails the last 3 tests due to timeout. Can I make the algorithm quicker?

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474018/appending-string-much-faster-than-appending-character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func index(_ i: String.Index, offsetBy n: String.IndexDistance) -> String.Index
```

is O(n), which means it gets slower as `n` increases.  So the longer your string, the slower your algorithm will run.

To access the characters in O(1) time, you should just use `for char in string.characters` to get the characters.

If you use `string.characters.enumerated()`, you will get a sequence of tuples that hold the index of the character and the character itself.  Then your code becomes:

```
func printEvenAndOdd(string: String) {
    var firstString = ""
    var secondString = ""

    for (index, char) in string.characters.enumerated() {
        if index % 2 == 0 {
            firstString += String(char)
        } else {
            secondString += String(char)
        }
    }
    print(firstString + " " + secondString)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Swift String reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string) the `index(_, offsetBy)` function performs with complexity `O(n)` leading to a total complexity of `O(n^2)`. The following function should perform better:

```
func printEvenAndOdd(string: String) {
    var firstString = ""
    var secondString = ""
    var i = 0

    for c in string.characters {
        if i % 2 == 0 {
            firstString += String(c)
        } else {
            secondString += String(c)
        }
        i += 1
    }
    print(firstString + " " + secondString)
}
```